# Moving to Italy from Denmark (EU Citizen) requirements

Tags: eu-citizens, relocation, italy

I'm moving from Copenhagen, Denmark to Northern Italy (Friuli-Venezia Guilia).
What requirements must I meet or check into before moving as an EU Citizen?

I will be living with my boyfriend.

Not in an immediate rush to get a job, but on the job market.

What are my options as far as job employment, and also where should I register with the Italian government ?

Comment: Does your boyfriend work in Italy? Is he himself an Italian citizen?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the EU website](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/residence/documents-formalities/registering-residence/italy/index_en.htm), you do need to register within three months of arriving (see also [poliziadistato.it](http://www.poliziadistato.it/articolo/view/10387/)). As an EU citizen, you have an unconditional right to take up employment or look for work but if you are inactive, you could have to prove that you have sufficient financial resources.

Since Denmark does not issue national ID cards, you will need a passport for most formalities. You cannot use a driving license or another type of ID like you would in other Nordic countries. Also, think about getting the (blue) European Health Insurance Card (should be free if you are covered by the Danish social security, but you do need to order it online).